# Google Calendars - Embedding into webpage loses one of the shared calendars

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

**Background**

So I have 3 google accounts:

- Account A
- Account B
- Account C

I want to share Account A and Account B's calendars on Account C.  I have initiated the sharing of calendars so that it appears like this when viewing from Account C:

[image]

I have Account C on both Account A and Account B as "Make changes and manage sharing"

When I view the calendar from calendar.google.com on Account C, I see all my events fine from all 3 calendars like I should.

**Problem**

So when I try to embed the calendar from Account C, I follow the instructions:

- Settings
- Click Account C
- Click Integrate Calendar
- Copy Embed code

Now when I view the embedded calendar, it shows items from Account C and A but Account B does not show up (even though it does when viewed from calendar.google.com). Is there a setting I need to change for Account B to show up? I do see that it is listed under "Other Calendars" instead of "My Calendars" so possibly this is the reason? I am not sure what triggers that too.

**Update**

I managed to get Account B to appear under "My Calendars" by ensuring that Account B allowed Account A to control it however it still will not appear on the embedded version..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what has to be done to share all 3 calendars with each other:

Account A:

- Goto Settings, Select Calendar, "Share with specific people", "Add People"
- Share in this way with both Account B and Account C
- Share as "Share all event details" or "Make changes and manage sharing"

Account B:

- Repeat same steps done in Account A but to share with Account B and Account C

Account C:

- Check that both Account A and Account C show up on the calendar under "My Calendars" and not "Other Calendars"
- If this is true then goto Settings, Select Calendar, "Integrate Calendar"
- Under Embed code click "Customize"
- Change the rest of the settings to whatever you want but the important part here is to check the "Calendars to Display". This changes the generated code appropriately to allow the other calendars. Once this is done then simply copy the HTML code at the top to your site. (**This is the part that I was missing**)